# Running wyd.pl in Cygwin - Can't locate object method "init" via package "wlgmod::doc"

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

After a few days of trying to get [wyd.pl](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2006/11/wyd-automated-password-profiling-tool/) running on my Windows 7 machine, I'm finally pretty close. I've installed a working version of Cygwin on what must be the 5th attempt, and I now have a working bash shell.

However, when running the following WyD command in bash:

`$ wyd.pl -b -e -t -s 3 -o "OUTPUTFILE" "TARGETDIRECTORY"`

...I get an error for a single missing dependency:

> Can't locate object method "init" via package "wlgmod::doc" (perhaps you forgot to load "wlgmod::doc"?) at /cygdrive/c/WYD/wyd.pl line 284.

Sometimes `wlgmod::doc` is replaced with `wlgmod:jpeg` or `wlgmod::plain`, but it's the same basic error. This is a welcome change from when I tried to run the program in CMD, which came back with tens of missing dependencies, but I'd like to figure out how to make this final one go away so I can finally run the program.

Looking in the directory where WyD is installed on Windows - `C:\WYD` - I see a folder called *wlgmod*, which contains `doc.pm`, `jpeg.pm`, `html.pm`, etc. Presumably, these are the 2packages" that bash is asking for, but judging by the output of the above error, it seems to be running WyD from that very same directory, so I'm confused as to why it can't find those files.

The only thing I can guess is that all this has something to do with the version of Perl being run. Doing `perl -v` in both consoles bolsters this a little.

```
CMD - V5.24.1
Cygwin/bash - V5.22.3
```

Other than that... I'm really confused and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

wyd.pl is perl script and it needs some perl modules to parse the files. Here’s how to resolve:

1. **Get `OpenOffice::OOD`**

> ```
> perl -MCPAN -e shell
>
> install OpenOffice::OOD
> ```

2. **Get [catdoc](http://mirror.amdmi3.ru/distfiles/)**

> ```
>  tar xzvf catdoc-0.94.tar.gz
>
>  ./configure
>
>  make
>
>  make install
> ```

3. **Get [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead)**

> ```
>   tar xzvf jhead-latest.tar.gz
>
>   cd jhead-2.90
>
>   make
> ```

4. **Get [mp3info](http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info)**

> ```
>  cd mp3info-0.8.5a
>
>  make mp3info
>
>  make install-mp3info
> ```

5. `apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

Comment: Can I ask how you knew it requires these modules? There is very little documentation on WyD out there. Is there a way to determine the modules/dependencies that a script like WyD uses that I don't know of?

Comment: @Hashim I got into the same situation years ago. At that time I googled it and found this solution and it solved my issue.