# Why do I get 'Can't locate object method "init" via package "wlgmod::odt"' when I try to run wyd.pl in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, bash, perl

I'm trying to run a Perl script called [WyD](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2006/11/wyd-automated-password-profiling-tool/) using Cygwin on Windows. Cygwin is installed at `C:\cygwin64`, and WyD is installed at `C:\wyd\wyd.pl`. Both are in the Windows `PATH` environment variable as `C:\cygwin64` and `C:\wyd` respectively.

When running WyD with bash/Mintty using:

`wyd.pl -b -e -t -s 3 -o "OUTPUTTEDWORDLIST" "TARGETFOLDER"`

...I get the following error:

> Can't locate object method "init" via package "wlgmod::odt" (perhaps
>   you forgot to load "wlgmod::odt"?) at /cygdrive/c/WYD/wyd.pl line 284.

Sometimes `wlgmod::odt` is replaced with `wlgmod::doc` or any other document type, but running the script always generates that same basic error.  A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930045/1191147) to this question recommended installing several dependencies, which turned out to be a mere copy-paste of an answer for Ubuntu systems, and didn't solve the error, so I've decided to start at the beginning and re-ask the question with more details. I also have all Perl packages in the Cygwin installer installed.

After everything I've tried and done to get this script working, I can personally think of two possible causes for the error. Think of these as a guide more than anything else.

1. The error above references line 284 in the `wyd.pl` script, so it's possible that something in that script is hardcoded so that it doesn't work with Cygwin/Windows, or just generally has a compatibility bug. I don't understand Perl, so I can't confirm this.
2. I notice that the installation of WyD at `C:\wyd` contains a folder called `wlgmod`, and that folder contains all the files that the above error seems to be looking for; `doc.pm`, `html.pm`, `jpeg.pm`, etc. If those files exist in that directory but bash is unable to find them, maybe it's due to the fact WyD needs to be run from within Cygwin itself. I've only recently thought about this possibility, and my knowledge of both Cygwin and WyD is too sparse to definitively know how both work. Is it even possible to run WyD from within the Cygwin folder? It's not a package so can't be installed as one, and therefore I'm not sure how that would work.

Here are the relevant sections of the script:

```
# Module hash containing module name and supported file extensions
# Multiple extensions are seperated using ';'
my %wlgmods = (
           'wlgmod::strings', '',           # only used with command-line switch
           'wlgmod::plain'  , '.txt',       # used for all MIME text/plain as well
           'wlgmod::html'   , '.html;.htm;.php;.php3;.php4',
           'wlgmod::doc'    , '.doc',
           'wlgmod::pdf'    , '.pdf',
           'wlgmod::mp3'    , '.mp3',
           'wlgmod::ppt'    , '.ppt',
           'wlgmod::jpeg'   , '.jpeg;.jpg;.JPG;.JPEG',
           'wlgmod::odt'    , '.odt;.ods;.odp'
           );

...

# Initialize possible modules
foreach(keys %wlgmods) {
    eval("use $_;");
    my $ret = $_->init(); # line 284

    # If module failed, add errortext and remove from hash
    if($ret) {
        $retvals .= "$_: $ret\n";
        delete $wlgmods{$_};
        $ret = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Line 283 of your pastebin is `eval("use $_;");`, where `$_` is wlgmod::odt at the point of failure. The `use` is failing, probably because wlgmod::odt is not in `@INC`; you can confirm by adding `die $@ if $@;` immediately after the `eval`. It should work if you run the script from `/cygdrive/c/WYD/` (since `.` is automatically included in `@INC` in most perl installations). But it would be better to add `use FindBin; use lib "$FindBin::Bin/wlgmod";` to the top of the script so you can run it from anywhere.

Comment: @MattJacob - That page doesn't seem to say an MCVE is required so much as recommended for "better answers". In this instance, I can't provide one due to not understanding Perl, though that's certainly not out of laziness or lack of work, as the days I've spent trying to resolve this issue so far attest to; I just don't have the time to learn a whole new language for this one use case. I don't see why that should be a barrier to asking a question about it.

Comment: The close reason literally says: 'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.' I don't know what could be clearer.

Comment: Correction, it should be just `use FindBin; use lib $FindBin::Bin;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Thanks so much, that did the trick. For the record, running from WyD directory itself also worked, which I really should have tried. The script is now running and working fine, except that it's giving an error `Wide character in print at line 157`. It's not fatal though, so I can definitely live with it to solve another day. You have no idea how grateful I am to you for finally helping me solve this. Bounty given.

Comment: @MattJacob - Fair enough if those are the rules, but I just don't see how that rule is productive. It seems self-defeating to require intimate knowledge of how a language and given program works - which reproducing the most minimal working code would require - from people there to learn how that language/program works. I don't ever remember Stack being this unnecessarily strict when I first joined.

Comment: Glad that worked. I added the relevant sections from your pastebin to the question and voted to reopen. We ask for an MCVE in the body of your question for several reasons: 1) It would be a pain for future visitors to wade through hundreds of lines of irrelevant code when they're searching for an answer to a similar problem. 2) If the link to pastebin breaks, future visitors won't be able to see the code that triggered the error message and their time will be wasted. 3) It can be difficult to impossible to track down an error without runnable code.

Comment: Fair enough. Again, thanks for the help. I said I'd give you bounty but I didn't realise you couldn't do that without an answer to award bounty to, my bad.

Comment: `$FindBin::RealBin` is safer than `$FindBin::Bin`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the reminder, I always forget about RealBin.